# Legendre symbol $\left(\frac 3p\right)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that:

$$\left(\frac 3p\right)= \begin{cases} p \equiv 1, 11 \pmod {12} \\ p\equiv 5, 7 \pmod {12} \end{cases}$$

where $\left(\frac 3p\right)$ is Legendre symbol

I have done this for $\left(\frac {-3}p\right)$ and reach $\left(\frac 3p\right) = 1$ if $p=1$ and $\left(\frac 3p\right)= -1$ if $p=2$. in the case where $p=1$ the next step was to see that $p=3k+1=6l+1$ so then $p=12j+1$ and $p=12j+11$ give $\left(\frac {-3}p\right)=1$.

I'm very confused about all of this so if someone could help it'd be greatly appreciated. it would probably be better to start from the beginning with $\left(\frac 3p\right)$ or to  use the same logic used to find $\left(\frac 2p\right)$ and Gauss lemma

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please use [MatHJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your post easier to read. It will surely increase your chances to get a helpful answer.

Comment: p can't be 1, because 1 is not prime nor composite number. Also I think that the problem is referring to prime numbers greater than 3.

By the way, check whether the edits are good and the context of the question isn't changed.